# How to apply an image to a CSS ordered list in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

How do I fix the conflict I'm running into when trying to style the UL in this blog post with check mark images. There's a style set up in the skin that is taking precedence over my style I've applied to the ul. Not sure how to over-ride it. I've tried every variation I can think of, and I'm sure it's just a basic misunderstanding of how things cascade. Can you help?

The post is here: http://alexisexhibits.com/trade-show-preparation-checklist

The CSS I have for the style is:

```
.checklist {
    list-style-image: url(http://alexisexhibits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/checkmark-ul.jpg) !important;
}
```

I know, the !important declaration is hackery, but oftentimes I find it necessary in dealing with CMS stuff, since the CSS is so piled on top of each other. In this case, it doesn't seem to help, but I left it.

The offending rule that allows the checks to show up if I disable it in Chrome Dev inspector is:

```
.shortcodes ul li {
    list-style: disc;
}
```

but I'm hesitant to change that as I don't want all `ul li` to change, just this specific one.

What's the right way to fix this? Any tips you can give on how to suss this sort of thing out for myself in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list-style-image` should be applied to the `<li>` not the `<ul>`

Like this:

```
.checklist li{
    list-style-image: url('http://alexisexhibits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/checkmark-ul.jpg') !important;
}
```